# SQL Cannot connect to database server

Tags: mysql, connection

Currently I have been working with `MySQL` on `Mac OSX`. I have `MySql Workbench` and `MySql` installed, along with commands on Terminal, but every time I try to open a database it comes up with this:
[image: Error]

Could someone explain what I have done wrong? I have tried everything (commands, reinstalling `MySQL`...)

Comment: Do you mean `Mysql`? i see dolphin there.. Sql are just language.. Not database..

Comment: The error occurs on MySQL, sorry for not adding that

Comment: Do you already tried do that error solver show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in ip address . make sure you use correct format. if you use it locally give "127.0.0.1:3306" or "localhost:3306"

Answer (score 0):

"8.0.13:3306" is not a legal "ip:port" format, make sure you've entered a correct IP address such as "10.8.0.13:3306"